# Keyboard AltGr/Ctrl/Shift stops working

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I've had this recurring problem lately that all the modifier keys <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>and <kbd>Shift</kbd> stop working. <kbd>Alt</kbd> still works, after a fashion.

I discovered the problem first when pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> stopped working. It just makes the menu flash on and off. Just pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> seems to activate the menues, though. Another example was when trying to type the `@` in an email address, and <kbd>AltGr</kbd> would not work, so it just entered a `2` instead -- the normal value of the key.

I've not experimented with it much, because it's been happening at bad times, but I will next time it occurs. The problem persists in all programs, like Firefox, WordPad, etc.

I tried restarting Firefox, but the only thing that works is restarting the computer. Then the problem immediately goes away. So it appears to be a software problem.

I am using Windows 7. My keyboard is old, perhaps 10+ years, but has been working flawlessly otherwise.

It is an Logitech "Elite" keyboard, the one with all the strange media buttons. Image here https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpJYo.jpg

A perhaps unrelated problem is that the mouse has been freezing, and then being released with a windows-error sound.

Any help to diagnose the problem would be very welcome. How would I go about finding out what is wrong?

Comment: Does this happen while in safe mode?

Comment: The word is "[modifer keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modifier_key)" for future reference

Comment: @Ramhound It would be very difficult to test that, since the problem goes away when rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

**Try another keyboard**, preferably one that doesn't require additional software like the Logitech does.

If this solves your problem you know the issue isn't with Windows. In this case, if you want to continue using your existing keyboard, you should uninstall and then reinstall your Logitech keyboard software. You can also try using the keyboard *without* that software.

Comment: That would be a problem, as this is already my backup keyboard, and the problem is intermittent and hard to predict. I am also not using any logitech drivers, it is whatever windows decided was needed.